# Connecting to grpc-web from Android

Tags: grpc-java, grpc-web

I am trying to connect to GRPC web server from Android client. I have tried using the ManagedChannelBuilder, AndroidChannelBuilder and OkHttpChannelBuilder but none of them seem to connect to grpc-web server, they can only connect to the GRPC server.

Is there any Android/Java client that I can use to connect to the https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web server?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used grpc-web, but my understanding is that you would need to use the [@improbable-eng/grpc-web](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/client/grpc-web) TypeScript library to access grpc-web servers.

A normal gRPC client, like the one you seem to be using, would not be able to communicate with a grpc-web server.

Comment: so is there anyway I can connect to the GRPC-web server from any Java client?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but maybe grpc-web has some way to allow calls to pass through? In general, if you wanted to connect from a Java client you would connect directly to the underlying gRPC server, not the grpc-web wrapper/proxy - that's for JavaScript clients.